# Is PRINCE2 truly in public domain?

Tags: methodology, prince2

I am a bit confused. I know PRINCE2 was released to be public domain in about 1990 but then I wonder why I cannot find any site (apart from prince2 wiki) with its content. Also, what is Axelos then an owner of - just the certification program? And what about PRINCE2 Agile, I thought that was developed by Axelos so that would not be in the public domain, I assume?

EDIT: On their website, Axelos mention (in Case Studies):

> It is public domain, available for anyone to use to manage a project,
> it can support the many requirements of CCA and CPIC, and it can be
> tailored to fit most any size project.

If I now understand it, then Axelos owns the PRINCE2 certifications + all materials they create, of course. But PRINCE2 itself is still in the public domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is and it isn't. Things like the terminology, the identity of the gates, the process flow ... are in the PD. This means that a company that uses P2 in their process can't be sued for copyright infringment by anyone else just because thy use these terms in a plan or contract. However, the rights of certification path rest with Axelos, so you do have to pay to become a practitioner, in the official sense.  Anyone can buy a textbook and adopt it informally of course.